# Inserting values for mysql table which is having auto increment id using java

Tags: java, mysql

when I run the application it's not showing any error but table was not updated correct me with showing the error:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO tree_msc (table_names) VALUES (?)";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = (PreparedStatement)
conn.prepareStatement(sql,Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
preparedStatement.setString(1, tble_name);
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Is the connection set to autoCommit? Have you tried committing the transaction?

Comment: I'm having id as auto increment and three other columns but i just want to insert only into the column called "table_name"

Comment: Yes, but what about the `Connection`?  If you don't commit the transaction, it won't be pushed to the database

Comment: no I wasn't. it works for me
Thanks.